# Making Tiles - Varying the Zoom Level by Population Density

Tags: tiles, tilemill, census, generate-tiles

I want to create map tiles for all of the United States at high zoom level (12 or 13).  I am using TileMill and mapping census tracts (income).

However, I only need the high zoom level for populated areas.  How could I exclude the areas with low population?

I want to do this to minimize tile generation time and webhost disk space.

For instance, I'm going to treat Alaska separately as most of it has low population density.  I can also exclude oceans and large lakes.  I could probably exclude a large portion of WY, ND, SD, and several other western states.

Comment: Tilemill uses mapnik.  So is there a way to do this with mapnik?